# NullPointerException with arguments of Navigation Components

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, arguments

I have the next problem. When I try to run my app Android Studio show me the next problem:

[Logcat error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuVAs.png)

My ArticleFragment code is the following:

```
import android.os.Bundle

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

import android.view.LayoutInflater

import android.view.View

import android.view.ViewGroup

import android.webkit.WebViewClient

import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil

import androidx.navigation.fragment.navArgs

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

import packagename.R

import packagename.databinding.FragmentArticleBinding

import packagename.ui.NewsActivity

import packagename.ui.NewsViewModel


class ArticleFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentArticleBinding
    lateinit var viewModel: NewsViewModel
    val args: ArticleFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_article, container, false)

        viewModel = (activity as NewsActivity).viewModel

        val article = args.article!!
        binding.webView.apply {
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            article.url?.let { loadUrl(it) }
        }

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.saveArticle(article)
            view?.let { it1 -> Snackbar.make(it1, "Article saved successfully!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me to fix this, please? I'm still trying to search an answer.

Comment: Did you make sure to pass a value to `article` variable ?

Comment: Please copy-paste the text of the error instead of a picture.

Comment: Could you add line 32 separately.